# how to read file from the phone memory in android?

Tags: android

I need to read the file from the phone memory.How read file ?can anyone help me??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to write in a file..

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("urls.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write("Alex".getBytes());
fos.close();
```

Here's how to read that file:

```
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("urls.txt");
int c;
while((c=fis.read())!=-1)
        {

            k += (char)c;
        }
fis.close();
```

String k will contain "Ankit" as a string.

Mind you.. the file "urls.txt" gets formed in the phone memory, you cannot access that file in your project as a resource.

For more information see:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: I have the file in the following path content://com.android.email.attachmentprovider/1/1/RAW how to read this?

Answer (score 0):

(via google search)

To read a file from internal storage:

1. Call [openFileInput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29) and pass it the name of the file to read. This returns a FileInputStream.
2. Read bytes from the file with [read()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)).
3. Then close the stream with close().

Ref: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: I have the file in the following path
content://com.android.email.attachmentprovider/1/1/RAW
how to read this?