# Android phone content information

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to read the content of mobile like directories with sub directories as well as files which are available in Android phone.

I have implemented an application for get the content of android phone as follows

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
// Browse in the following folder.
Uri startDir = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
// Files and directories
intent.setDataAndType(startDir, "vnd.android.cursor.dir/lysesoft.andexplorer.file");
```

Can I get the directories and files without using **andexplorer.file**.or is there any way to get the content of android phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not completely clear what you mean by "get the content of android phone".  If you are talking about a list of files and directories, here is a trivial file explorer app that shows how:

```
package com.explorenm.filelist;

import java.io.File;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FileList extends ListActivity {
    private String startdir = "/";
    private File workingdir = new File(startdir);
    private Context ctx;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ctx = this;

        if (workingdir.exists()) {
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx, R.layout.listitem, workingdir.list()));           
            ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true); // allow user to type to go to a specific item in the list      
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                        File selection = (workingdir.listFiles())[position];
                        if (selection.isDirectory()) {
                            workingdir = selection;
                            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx, R.layout.listitem, workingdir.list()));       
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selection.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                }
              });
            //registerForContextMenu(lv);
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
                tv.setText(workingdir.getAbsolutePath() + " does not exist.");
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming the file has been made readable by the app (or you are root on a rooted device), you can use standard Java techniques to read the file contents; how has been answered in other questions, such as [how to read file from the phone memory in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316629/how-to-read-file-from-the-phone-memory-in-android)